# convert decoded path to coordinates in javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have this Encoded path `encodedPath` which equally `oyky@e}|kGpv@kzE`, then i tried to decode it using `decodePath` like this:

```
 decodeString = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(encodeString);
```

here is when i console log it `console.log(decodeString);

[image]

but when I **alert** it, this is the exact data:

> (9.5684, 44.062430000000006),(9.559510000000001, 44.097530000000006)

So, my question is, **Is this data convertable to path again and draw polyline with it ?**
because when I tried to draw a polyline like this:

```
var path = [
   (9.5684, 44.062430000000006),
   (9.559510000000001, 44.097530000000006)
]

var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: d,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 5
});
polyline.setMap(map);
```

It is showing this:

> InvalidValueError: at index 0: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral with finite coordinates: not an Object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath`](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geometry#encoding.decodePath) returns an array of [`google.maps.LatLng`](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLng) objects, you can pass the value returned directly into the `path` property of the polyline:

```
var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
  strokeColor: '#000000',
  strokeOpacity: 1,
  strokeWeight: 3,
  map: map,
  path: google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath("oyky@e}|kGpv@kzE")
});
```

(your `path` array is not a valid JavaScript array)

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/e7wcntds/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 14,
    center: {
      lat: 34.366,
      lng: -89.519
    }
  });
  var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
    strokeColor: '#000000',
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    map: map,
    path: google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath("oyky@e}|kGpv@kzE")
  });
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < poly.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
    bounds.extend(poly.getPath().getAt(i));
    console.log(poly.getPath().getAt(i).toUrlValue(6));
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=geometry&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```